# quadratic equation precalculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

from Stewart, Precalculus, 5th, p56, Q. 79

Find all real solutions of the equation

$$\dfrac{x+5}{x-2}=\dfrac{5}{x+2}+\dfrac{28}{x^2-4}$$

my solution

$$\dfrac{x+5}{x-2}=\dfrac{5}{x+2}+\dfrac{28}{(x+2)(x-2)}$$
$$(x+2)(x+5)=5(x-2)+28$$
$$x^2+2x-8=0$$

$$\dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt{4+32}}{2}$$
$$\dfrac{-2\pm6}{2}$$
$$x=-4\text{ or }2$$

official answer at the back of the book has only one real solution of $-4$

where did I go wrong?

Comment: values of variable on which functions is define means function have value called as domain.If you put x=2 in your question two functions will be undefined that's why in the answer only 1 value is consider

Comment: The very first thing I thought when I looked at the original equation is that $2$ and $-2$ cannot be solutions.  That's something to look for.  And I have no doubt that what Stewart had in mind is precisely that some students would do just what you did here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You multiplied both sides by $(x-2)(x+2)$.  If this is zero, you may introduce extra solutions, hence you need to check your final answer to see if you have any extraneous solutions.  In this case, you do!  For $x=2$, two of the three fractions in the original equation are undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Why do we have to reject the solution $x=2$?

Hint: What happens when we put $x=2$ in the original equation?
Review your equations. Make sure that you didn't multiply by 0.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x+5}{x-2}=\frac{5}{x+2}+\frac{28}{x^2-4}$$
multiply both sides with $(x-2)(x+2)\neq 0$ or $x\neq 2,x\neq -2$
we get
$$(x+5)(x+2)=5(x-2)+28,x\neq 2,-2$$

$$x^2+2x-8=0,x\neq 2,-2$$

$$x^2-2x+4x-8=0,x\neq 2,-2$$
$$x(x-2)+4(x-2)=0,x\neq 2,-2$$
$$(x-2)(x+4)=0,x\neq 2,-2$$
so $x+4=0$ or $x=-4\neq 2,-2$ is unique solution because from $x-2=0$ follow solution $x=-2$ that is prohibited

Answer (score 1):

The given equation is this  $\dfrac{x+5}{x-2}=\dfrac{5}{x+2}+\dfrac{28}{x^2-4}$

$$\frac{x+5}{x-2}-\frac{5}{x+2}=\frac{28}{x^2-4}\\\frac{(x+5)(x+2)-5(x-2)}{x^2-4}=\frac{28}{x^2-4}\\x^2+2x-8=0 :\ where \ x\neq 2, because \ we \ multiply \ with \  x^2-4 \ both \ sides \\ x^2-2x+4x-8=0,x\neq 2\\x(x-2)+4(x-2)=0,x\neq2 \\(x-2)(x+4)=0,x\neq 2$$ after solving this quadratic equation we get $$x=-4 \ and\ 2$$ and we have already excluded the solution $x=2$, so this equation has only one real solution.